# Connect camera to Raspberry pi via gpio pins

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

is there anyway to connect wires from a camera to gpio pins on a Pi to use/control the camera?
In my case this is the camera.
[image]

Something like this, but I don't actually know how to connect it.
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware interfacing rather than programming. Maybe try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com I think you are out of luck though as it produces composite video and Raspberry Pi could only input that via a DVR adapter.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you anyways.